# Vue rerenders component once a single element changes

Tags: vue.js

I found out that when an element in a Vue Component changes, the whole component will get rerendered. [Check out this fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/axjz0grt/1/) In the console you can see that `test` is called every time the `count` value changes.

How does that impact performance? Imagine `test` would be a more performance heavy operation, it would be really performance heavy if the `test` function is called every second even though the value doesn't change.

Could this lead to performance issues? Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Computed Properties` instead of making a method to perform a one-time operation.

```html
<div id="app">
  <h1>{{test}}</h1>
  <div>
    <h2>{{count}}</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
  computed: {
    test() {
        console.log('I got rerenderd!')
      return 'Hello'    
    }
  },
  methods: {
    startCount() {
        setInterval(() => {
        this.count++;
      }, 1000)
    }
  },
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Jokerwin/tnvcyw1d/3/

See more in the docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: Thanks, I know about computed and I know that in this case I should use it. The question was more about the performance aspect if I would do it this way. Also why does vue not rerender the `h1` when I computed or just a data/prop object? Whats the difference to using a function?

Comment: Okay, definitly you don't have to do in this way because you are not calling `test()` explicitly to execute. As you said: `Imagine test would be a more performance heavy operation, it would be really performance heavy if the test function is called every second even though the value doesn't change.` This is correct and you don't have to do in this way unless you have a good reason.